# Show a loader since iframe takes time to load in React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, iframe

Using ReactJS (+TailwindCSS), I am trying to show a loading screen while the iframe loads the content.
I tried using `onLoad` but it didn't work:

```
const [isIframeLoading, setIsIframeLoading] = useState(true);
return (
 <div className="flex justify-center items-center w-full xm:w-3/4 h-full">
  {isIframeLoading
    ? <div className={" h-[750px] w-[700px] bg-ac-gray2 brightness-75 mt-4 rounded-lg animate-pulse"}></div>
    : <iframe className={" w-full h-full min-h-[1250px] calendly:min-h-[750px] border-0 box-border"}
             src={calendlyEmbed}
             onLoad={() => setIsIframeLoading(false)}
             title='Select a Date & Time - Calendly'
      ></iframe>
 </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

In the code, we render the loading but never render the Iframe. Thus, the onLoad is never called.

Try this

```
{isIframeLoading
    ? <div className={" h-[750px] w-[700px] bg-ac-gray2 brightness-75 mt-4 rounded-lg animate-pulse"}></div> : null }

<iframe className={" w-full h-full min-h-[1250px] calendly:min-h-[750px] border-0 box-border"}
             src={calendlyEmbed}
             onLoad={() => setIsIframeLoading(false)}
             title='Select a Date & Time - Calendly'
      ></iframe>
```